# how to pass data to next page in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, coldfusion

currently i doing Highchart in ColdFusion. I want to pass my data in Highchart to next page when i click on the x-axis' label. The charts i doing is spiderweb. For a scenario,i have x-axis label like 'Overall','Appt Booking', 'Reception', 'Service Advisor', 'Completion Delivery Process'. When i click on overall, the data in overall axis are pass to next page in the link i going. So anyone can guide me how to do it? I manage to link to the page i want,now i just dunno how to get the data to pass to next page.

Below is my code,TQ.

```html
<cfscript>
  categories= ['Overall','Appt Booking', 'Reception', 'Service Advisor', 'Completion Delivery Process'] ;

 series = [{
            'name': 'Last Month',
            'data': [3.775,3.5, 3.9, 4, 3.7],
            'pointPlacement': 'on'
        }, {
            'name': 'MTD',
            'data': [ 3.775, 3.7, 3.5, 3.9, 4],
            'pointPlacement': 'on'
        }, {
            'name': 'Target',
            'data': [3.725, 3.8,3.5, 3.7, 3.9],
            'pointPlacement': 'on',
             'url': 'https://www.google.com/'
        }];
</cfscript>

<html>

<head> 
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="exporting.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts-more.js"></script>

  
<script>
$(function () {
    
    var categoryLinks = {
        'Overall': 'http://127.0.0.1:8500/highCharts/Spiderweb.cfm?id=1234',
        'Appt Booking': 'http://127.0.0.1:8500/highCharts/line.cfm',
        'Service Advisor': 'http://127.0.0.1:8500/highCharts/combine.cfm'
    };

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            polar: true,
            type: 'line'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Budget vs spending',
            x: -1000
        },

        pane: {
            size: '70%'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: <cfoutput>#serializeJson(categories)#</cfoutput>,
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            lineWidth: 0,
             labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<a href="' + categoryLinks[this.value] + '">' +
                        this.value + '</a>';
                }
            }

        },

        yAxis: [{
            gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 3,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true,
            tickPositions: [3,3.5, 4, 4.5, 5],
        }],

          plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.2f}</b><br/>'
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 70,
            layout: 'vertical'
        },

        series: <cfoutput>#serializeJson(series)#</cfoutput>

    });
});
</script> 

</head>

<body>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What's the data? You can pass the data back on your link or in a form param using urlencoded json I suppose. Typically though something like highcharts is more of a responsive app rather than page by page - where you redraw a new chart based on your clicking.

Comment: hello, the data i want to pass is the value of the chart, for example when i click on 'Overall', the data of the overall will pass to the link

Comment: You are doing this right now, for example: `http://127.0.0.1:8500/highCharts/Spiderweb.cfm?id=1234` - `id=1234` should be passed on.

Comment: ya i know that one i try it before, what mean is when i click on "overall", the value is passing automatically

Comment: You somehow need to tell (us and your app) **what** you want to pass on.

Comment: Guessing here: Your chart is going to have a listener object (check the highcharts docs) that "receives" the click with arguments. Part of the args are going to be that value (probably). once you find the object in your listener object you can relocated and pass it on - or whatever. But you are going to have to dig into highcharts a lot deeper to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```js
labels: {
    formatter: function () {
        location.href = categoryLinks[this.value];
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
return '<a href="' + categoryLinks[this.value] + '">' + this.value + '</a>';`
```